# Form the differential equations of the family of circles touching two given parallel lines $y=\pm a$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Form the differential equations of the family of circles touching two given parallel lines $y=\pm a$

**My Attempt:**

Let the family of circles be $(x-h)^2+y^2=a^2$, with $(h,0)$ being the centre and $a$ being the radius.

Differentiating w.r.t. x, we get,

$$2(x-h)+2yy'=0\\ \implies yy'+x=h$$

Differentiating again, I get,

$$yy''+(y')^2+1=0$$

But the answer given is

$$y^2(1+(y')^2)=a^2$$

Comment: In your approach you have not made use of the fact that the circle must touch $y=\pm a\,.$ Such circles are obviously those that have center on the $y$-axis (not $x$-axis as you assumed) and radius $a$: $x^2+(y-h)^2=a^2$. Then $y=h\pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,.$ Now use $y'=\mp x/(y-h)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Hi, I still think the centre should be on x-axis. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I mixed them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation, the solution of which depends on two arbitrary constants, cannot be an acceptable differential equation defining the family (one of the constants being $a$, that is determined, and the other $h$). We can use the equation for the family to get rid of the constant.

$$(x-h)^2+y^2=a^2$$

$$2(x-h)+2yy'=0\\ \implies (x-h)^2=y^2(y')^2$$

But $(x-h)^2=a^2-y^2$

$$\dfrac{a^2-y^2}{y^2}=(y')^2$$

$$\dfrac{a^2}{y^2}-1=(y')^2$$

Finally
$$a^2=y^2(1+(y')^2)$$

Comment: Hi. Why can't $a$ be free? Is $a$ not an arbitrary constant here? I think $a$ can be $1$ or $2$ or anything else

Comment: $a$ can be anything but it's **given**, so is, determined, not arbitrary. The solution for the equation you propose is $y^2+(x+c_2)^2=c_1$. We cannot make the identification $c_1=a^2$ without an extra stipulation, so is, the differential equation **by itself** doesn't determine the family. In fact, that equation your propose gives the family of circles with center on the $X$ axis with any radius.

Comment: Thanks, got it.